# Issue pivoting out Data (Currency Causing the issue)

Tags: sql

I am creating a view that will pivot out Value Types for a set of data. The issue is that I have 5 unique values for currency (EUR, USD, MYR, CYN, NULL), and yes I realize NULL is not a value, but NULL is the issue. While I do want a different line of data for different currencies, I do not want a different line for NULL, as NULL simply means that Currency isn't used in that specific value type (SalesVolume). The same thing happens with UOM. I simply want a single line of data (for each currency (There is only a single UOM)). Here is my query:

```
SELECT Year, Period, [Year-Period], Region, [Op Co] AS OpCo, PMC, [PMC Description] AS PMCDescription, Currency, UOM,
MAX(CASE WHEN [Value Type] = 'Net Revenue' THEN Value END) AS NetRevenue,
MAX(CASE WHEN [Value Type] = 'Sales Volume' THEN Value END) AS SalesVolume,
MAX(CASE WHEN [Value Type] = 'Std Gross Margin' THEN Value END) AS StdGrossMargin,
[Customer Relationship] AS CustomerRelationship
FROM gdw.FactBudgetSummaryNew
GROUP BY Year, Period, [Year-Period], Region, [Op Co], PMC, [PMC Description], Currency, UOM, [Customer Relationship]
```

I currently get this:
[image]

But, as you can see, for Sales Volume, the value for Currency is NULL, which causes an additional column, I'd like it to just combine.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems up have different data mixed up together. Try calculating grouping by `UOM` (if it's just 1 different value) separately from the `Currency` grouping.

```
;WITH UOMData AS
(
    SELECT 
        Year, 
        Period, 
        [Year-Period], 
        Region, 
        [Op Co] AS OpCo, 
        PMC, 
        [PMC Description] AS PMCDescription, 
        UOM,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Value Type] = 'Sales Volume' THEN Value END) AS SalesVolume,
        [Customer Relationship] AS CustomerRelationship
    FROM 
        gdw.FactBudgetSummaryNew
    WHERE
        UOM IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        Year, 
        Period, 
        [Year-Period], 
        Region, 
        [Op Co], 
        PMC, 
        [PMC Description], 
        UOM, 
        [Customer Relationship]
),
CurrencyData AS
(
    SELECT 
        Year, 
        Period, 
        [Year-Period], 
        Region, 
        [Op Co] AS OpCo, 
        PMC, 
        [PMC Description] AS PMCDescription, 
        Currency, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Value Type] = 'Net Revenue' THEN Value END) AS NetRevenue,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Value Type] = 'Std Gross Margin' THEN Value END) AS StdGrossMargin,
        [Customer Relationship] AS CustomerRelationship
    FROM 
        gdw.FactBudgetSummaryNew
    WHERE
        Currency IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        Year, 
        Period, 
        [Year-Period], 
        Region, 
        [Op Co], 
        PMC, 
        [PMC Description], 
        Currency, 
        [Customer Relationship]
)
SELECT
    M.Year, 
    M.Period, 
    M.[Year-Period], 
    M.Region, 
    M.OpCo, 
    M.PMC, 
    M.PMCDescription, 
    M.UOM, 
    C.Currency,
    M.CustomerRelationship,
    M.SalesVolume,
    C.StdGrossMargin,
    C.NetRevenue
FROM
    UOMData AS M
    INNER JOIN CurrencyData AS C ON
        M.Year = C.Year AND
        M.Period = C.Period AND
        M.[Year-Period] = C.[Year-Period] AND
        M.Region = C.Region AND
        M.OpCo = C.OpCo AND
        M.PMC = C.PMC AND
        M.PMCDescription = M.PMCDescription AND
        M.CustomerRelationship = C.CustomerRelationship
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
MAX(CASE
        WHEN [Value Type] = 'Net Revenue' AND UOM IS NOT NULL THEN Value
    END) AS NetRevenue,
MAX(CASE
        WHEN [Value Type] = 'Sales Volume' AND Currency IS NOT NULL THEN Value
    END) AS SalesVolume,
MAX(CASE
        WHEN [Value Type] = 'Std Gross Margin' AND UOM IS NOT NULL THEN Value
    END) AS StdGrossMargin,
[Customer Relationship] AS CustomerRelationship
FROM gdw.FactBudgetSummaryNew
GROUP BY YEAR,
         Period,
         [Year-Period],
         Region,
         [Op Co],
         PMC,
         [PMC Description],
         Currency,
         UOM,
         [Customer Relationship]
```

Comment: When I do that I get no values because, if the Value Type is Sales Volume, then currency is NULL and if Value Type is NetRevenue or StdGrossMargin, then UOM is NULL.